# How add padding or margin for ImageView in JavaFX by using code (not FXML)

Tags: javafx, imageview, margin, padding

I want add white border around ImageView.

[image: Buttons]

One solution is to wrap the images in a Button.

And I try use StackPane:

```
StackPane stackPaneforImageActivity = new StackPane();

        Image activityImage = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
        ImageView imv = new ImageView(activityImage);

        newActivityHBox.getChildren().add(stackPaneforImageActivity);

        stackPaneforImageActivity.getChildren().add(imv);

        stackPaneforImageActivity.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        stackPaneforImageActivity.setStyle("-fx-border-color:white;-fx-background-color: black;");

        imv.setFitHeight(30);
        imv.setFitWidth(30);
```

[image: ImageView in StackPane]

But

Are there other solutions?

But the image is outside the StackPane. Why?

Comment: Wrapping in a `Button` doesn't seem like a sensible approach, unless you actually want the functionality (pressing, actions, etc) of a `Button`. Why not just wrap it in a `StackPane` with border and padding set (either in Java or in CSS)?

Comment: James_D. I did as you advised. But for some reason the ImageView is outside of the Stackpane. How to fix it?

Comment: Looks like maybe you forgot to remove the code where you add the image view to whatever container it was previously in (an `HBox`?). You should just add the stack pane, but not the image view itself?

Comment: No. Initially, all the buttons are in HBox. The ImageView is added dynamically to HBox after buttons. (After choose file from desktop using FileChooser). I wrap the ImageView in StackPane. And StackPane add to HBox.